# multiple independent websockets connections

Tags: python, django, angular, websocket, django-channels

I have been playing around with django channels + angular. I have created an app that simply sends notifications to front end with a counter 1,2,3,4. It works fine, except if I open the page in multiple tabs. I am also not able to disconnect from the websocket, I can use unsubscribe but it does not really  close the connection but that's more kind of a angular question. Anyways how can I make my socket multithread, So if I make multiple requests from the same computer but from different tabs it will work and 2 different instances of the consumer will be created therefore, If I load 2 pages in the same computer the counter should be different independently increasing counter. Do I need redis for that ?

Comment: What you want is the default behaviour. If you create separate connections from the angular side in each tab, then you will have separate connections on the Django side. What exactly happens when you open separate tabs currently? you should ass that to your question. As for redis, you will need a functioning Channel layer (Redis, Rabbit-MQ, etc) to achieve group messaging across different server instances and other things in Channels but not specifically for this

Comment: when I open 2 tabs one of them will freeze and the front end wont receive anything actually it seems like both messages sent from the server goes to the most recent page opened. only one connection is allowed. i am running it locally maybe this is causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my url router was missing .as_asgi()
this worked:

`URLRouter([path('wscrawpredict', CrawPredictConsume.as_asgi(),name="wscraw")])`